# I am facing difficulty in loading a JSON file into MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

When tried to import the JSON file using `mongoimport` I got this error:

> "Failed: an inserted document is too large"

[I tried using batch size too, but still, I am getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr4em.png)

```
mongoimport --db=enviact --collection=eactdata --file=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\databk2L.json

mongoimport --db=enviact --collection=eactdata --file=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\databk2L.json --batchSize=1
```

Comment: Try splitting into multiple files with smaller chunks

Comment: What is the content of that file? It's not a single JSON array, is it?

Answer (score 1):

If your document exceeds 16MB you need to use the GridFS API to get it loaded.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/